# Bash script to automatically close a process given the process name

Tags: bash, shell-script

As you might have guessed from the title i'm trying to write a bash script to close all processes given a program name, but have close to 0 experience in doing that. What i've found is that with:

```
ps -aux | grep $processToClose
```

i can get all the processes with the name, but then to kill them i just manually use:

```
kill -9 $processPID
```

Any idea on how i could automate the process killing part?

*(if you want to know why i want to do such thing: i use anydesk on my work laptop and my everyday PC so that i have to use just one, but sometimes (basically every day) anydesk chooses to not work and so i have to close it using the commands i wrote above)*

Comment: How about killall command? https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html

Comment: The output of `ps` is not easy to parse programmatically with columns that may be empty.  That what probably a motivation in building alternatives like  `killall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `pkill` is for.

```
pkill regexp
```

Kills (with SIGTERM like with `kill`, you generally don't want to use SIGKILL (9)) the processes whose name (as reported by `ps` or `ps -o comm`) matches the regular expression.

```bash
pkill -f regexp
```

For those whose arglist (assuming they or one of their ancestors have executed a command) as reported by `ps -f` (or `ps -o comm` or your BSD-style `ps aux`) matches the extended regexp.

Add the `-x` option for the regexp to match the name/arglist as a whole. For instance, so that `pkill -x xterm` kills the processes running `xterm` and not the ones running `lxterm` or `xterminator` as `pkill xterm` would.

So to kill the processes whose name is stored in `$processToClose` and assuming `$processToClose` doesn't contain regexp operators (`\|$^*()+[]{}.?`):

```
pkill -x -- "$processToClose"
```

If it contains or may contain regexp operators, they would need to be escaped with `\`:

```bash
LC_ALL=C pkill -x -- "$(
  printf '%s\n' "$processToClose" |
    LC_ALL=C sed 's/[][\\|$^*()+{}.?]/\\&/g')"
```

Here also setting the locale to C for both `pkill` and `sed` to allow process names that don't necessarily form valid text in the users locale.

To see what processes `pkill` would kill, you can replace `pkill` with `pgrep -l`.

`pgrep`/`pkill` are not standard commands but are very common.

`ps` is standard but very unportable. The list of options and the output format varies greatly between implementations. In particular, your `ps -aux` is likely only going to work with the `procps` implementation of `ps` (the one typically found on Linux-based systems). That's the BSD-style `ps aux` but with a spurious `-` in front.

The list of options specified by POSIX is very limited.

```
ps -A -o pid= -o comm= |
  NAME=$processToClose awk '
    NF == 2 && $2 "" == ENVIRON["NAME"] {print $1}' |
  xargs kill
```

Assuming `$processToClose` and process names don't contain whitespace would be a standard approach.

Answer (score -3):

ps -aux |grep $processName |awk '{print $2}'| xargs -I {} kill {}

Comment: This is a very fragile approach which will fail in various cases. Assuming you mean `$processName` and not `$processPID`, you will also find and kill any process whose name may contain `$processName`. If you grep for `ls`, you will also find `lshw` etc. You will also be finding the `grep` itself. But, really, there's already tools for this; `pkill` and `killall` both do what the OP wants in a safer and simpler way.

Comment: ahhh yes , it should be $processName T_T

Comment: You could make this slightly better/simpler with `ps aux | awk -v p="$procName" '$0~p{print $2}' | xargs kill`, but really it will always be risky :/